# Jasper Report Gantt XSD not matching supported features

Tags: java, xml, hyperlink, xsd, jasper-reports

I am trying to use hyperlinks inside a PDF document. I want to create hyperlinks from Gantt Chart Bars to a row in a table. 
I used Japser Report Designer 6.3.1 to create my report. I added hyperlinks pointing to the table row for the Gantt Data.

However if I compile the report I get a schema Validation Error

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 265; columnNumber: 68; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'itemHyperlink'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":percentExpression}' is expected.

This is my Gantt Dataset:

```
<ganttDataset>
<dataset>
    <datasetRun subDataset="dgGanttEvents" uuid="cc974cc8-20f5-4a4c-88cd-9c5e0c46bada">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{dgGanttSeries}]]></dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
</dataset>
<ganttSeries>
    <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{series}]]></seriesExpression>
    <taskExpression><![CDATA[$F{task}]]></taskExpression>
    <subtaskExpression><![CDATA[$F{subtask}]]></subtaskExpression>
    <startDateExpression><![CDATA[$F{start}]]></startDateExpression>
    <endDateExpression><![CDATA[$F{end}]]></endDateExpression>
    <itemHyperlink hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
        <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{time}-$F{series}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
    </itemHyperlink>
</ganttSeries>
```

Line Number 265 is at the *itemHyperlink* Tag.

I am confused that I can use the field in the editor but they seem to be not supported. Furthermore I looked into the sources of 
[JRDesignGanttSeries.java @ Github](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/6.3.0.x/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/charts/design/JRDesignGanttSeries.java) and I can also find that

```
String PROPERTY_ITEM_HYPERLINK = "itemHyperlink";
```

seems to be supported

I tried to switch off validation according to the documentation with

```
net.sf.jasperreports.compiler.xml.validation=false
```

Taken from: [JasperCompileManager Java Doc](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperCompileManager.html)

But then I get

```
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Error creating SAX parser.
....
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException: Property 'http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage' must be set before setting property 'http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource'. 
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setProperty(Unknown Source)
```

- Any ideas why the XSD is different from the features that seem to be
  supported?
- Any Idea how the create hyperlinks from Gantt Chart Bars?
- How to turn off XSD Validation in Japser Reports so it does not blow
  up?

Comment: Have you tried adding `itemHyperlink` as the error indicates is expected before (or instead of) `percentExpression`?   Turning off validation might suppress the validation error but very well may result in a new error if the consuming application's requirements (as expressed in the XSD) are not fullfilled.

Comment: @kjhughes I thought the same. But reordering doesn't make any difference and from the jasper report XSD it's obvious that it's not part of the schema at all: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html#ganttSeries

Comment: Note that the error message indicates that the expected element is in a specific namespace.  If you're not familiar with XML namespaces, they can be tricky to get right.  I see no namespaces in your posted XML, so there's a chance your problem is related.  If I had a link to the complete XSD and actual XML, I could tell you for sure.  Otherwise, this is just speculation.